# Bypass Command Q in Mac in JavaFX

Tags: java, macos, javafx

I am creating an application in JavaFx(Mac OS) for which I need to handle the Command-Q which makes the application to Quit.I don't want my application to Quit on (CMD + Q). Unfortunately being an OS event no keyhandler/listener is helping me out to trap Command+Q.

I have researched and found few posts for Java (and not JavaFX) which refer me to **com.apple.eawt** package but this thing doesn't seem to work without Swing support.I am not using any swing component and does not wish to enclose any JFXPanel etc. in my javaFx app.

Isn't there any way to trap and bypass this (CMD + Q) call and save my application from quitting ?

Comment: Strange no one bothers !!!! Is it that hard ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok nevermind, it is solved.
Actually I was handling the event on child window(Stage) and not the parent Stage.Command Q is a system level event which is not trapped by child windows and can only be trapped by root Stage of javaf Application.

Comment: This is not an answer, even if you did solve it yourself you didn't explain how you did it...please update your answer.